# Trying to find where Acrobat 9.x setPersistent stores variables

Tags: acrobat, acrobat-sdk

According the horrifically documented API for Javascript for Acrobat API reference (V.9.1), **setPersistent** stores persistent variables as follows

> Upon application exit, persistent global variables are stored in the
>   glob.js file located in the user’s folder for folder-level scripts and
>   re-loaded at application start

I can not find that file on my mac - hidden or otherwise.

Anyone know a) where the glob.js file is located or b) where adobe actually does store persistent variables

Answer (score 1):

You may find the user’s folder for folder level scripts by executing *app.getPath(“user”, “javascript”)* ([p. 42, Adobe, 2006](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_developer_guide.pdf#page=42)). The method *app.getPath* may only be executed during batch or console event ([p. 124, Adobe, 2007](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf#page=124)).

### References

Adobe Systems Incorporated (2007). Adobe Acrobat SDK 8.1 JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference for Microsoft Windows and Mac OS. Edition 2.0, April 2007. [Electronic Version](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf). San Jose, CA: Adobe Systems Incorporated.

Adobe Systems Incorporated (2006). Adobe® Acrobat ® SDK 8.0 Developing Acrobat Applications Using JavaScript for Microsoft® Windows® and Mac OS®. Edition 1.0, November 2006. [Electronic Version](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_developer_guide.pdf). San Jose, CA: Adobe Systems Incorporated.